# decimal number comma styling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some "double" values in a gridview on an aspx page. I need to use comma-styling in these values like:

original value = 1986.05
required value = 19,86.05

original value = 51986.05
required value = 5,19,86.05

I am using the following code for this:

```
e.Row.Cells[6].Text = String.Format("{0:##,##,##.##}", Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[6].Text));
```

It is showing the value as 1,986.05 but I need it as 19,86.05

Please help!

Comment: @ckuri... it is still showing as 1,986.05

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a custom `CultureInfo` with 2-digit number grouping to achieve this:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(string.Empty, true)
{
    NumberFormat = { NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 2 } }
};
Console.WriteLine((1986.05).ToString("N", culture));
```

Output:

```
19,86.05
```

The documentation set for `NumberGroupSizes` is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes) that describes this.

In your code you could implement it like:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(string.Empty, true)
{
    NumberFormat = { NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 2 } }
};
e.Row.Cells[6].Text = Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[6].Text).ToString("N", culture);
```

Comment: amazing.... thanks Martin..

one more question on this... arise due to a curiosity... lol ... How can we use the same thing to separate a number as 12,34,567 when the number originally was 1234567 ?

Comment: @DeepakVerma See the example in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @DeepakVerma Sorry for the delay in replying.  Just modify the group sizes as appropriate, so in your example: `{2,2,3}`. As canton7 mentioned, the docs show how to adjust these with some examples :)